# scanf in loop should react to EOF signal, but it does not

Tags: c

I have this piece of code which reads numbers `float` and it should stop after receiving `EOF` single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> but it just doesn't react.

Any help please?

(I know it looks weird but that `-1` control is there for a reason.)

```
do {
  f++;
  scanf("%f",&paid[f]);
} while(paid[f-1] != 0 && paid[f] != EOF);
```

Comment: Test the return value from `scanf` which should be `1` (number of items converted). `EOF` is not a value that that will turn up in your array `float paid[]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for quick reactions. It reacts on like 4th press though...

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried, with the actual inputs, outputs and expected outputs, which shows the problem. Otherwise we can ask questions all day, such as "did you `#include <stdio.h>`"

Comment: The returned value from the call to `scanf()` needs to be checked, not the parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EOF` is the return value of `scanf()`, not the value written to passed memory address.

```
do {
    f++;
} while(scanf("%f", &paid[f]) != EOF && paid[f - 1] != 0);
```